# Song lyrics and timings

Tags: data-request, music

I'm creating animations of songs with their words.

I'm looking for data with lyrics and timings for common songs.

Some sort of karaoke database comes to mind, though so far I haven't found anything good.

Any ideas?

Comment: What license do you need? Free? If not what is your budget?

Answer (score 1):

Sheet music and MIDI comes to mind. You could use XML versions of sheet music to get the timing... http://www.musicxml.com/music-in-musicxml/

You need to add personal touches to music  composition to make it soulful. Otherwise, it can come off as being very cold.

You could also look at music videos with closed caption or subtitles as a way to extract lyrics and timing.