# Music lyrics timing data

Tags: data-request, music

I wonder if there is a database or technique of collecting the timings of a song?

I found [this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/song-lyrics-and-timings) post linking to [MusicXML](http://www.musicxml.com/music-in-musicxml/). However, it seems MusicXML is for sheet music. I am looking for data relating to music of the more general variety.

**I'm looking for something that gives the lyrics of a song as well as the time in the song a lyric occurs.**

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: What kind of license do you need? Freely re-usable?

Comment: Ideally free but I'm open to any license the best option has to offer

Answer (score 3):

*(Not a very practical answer, but maybe can get the ball rolling...)*

If you can create a list Youtube links to the songs or albums you want, you can download the captions (subtitles). These have a timestamp along with the lyrics.

With YouTube you can search for videos with captions. Unfortunately, I found that many are listed with captions but actually don't have any meaningful text.

[image]

Here is an example of one video with good captions ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VImAM8a5Y-w)).

[image]

You can see the transcript by going to "More" and then "Transcript".

[image]

---

One tool to do download captions is called [Google2SRT](http://google2srt.sourceforge.net/en/).

> **What is Google2SRT?** Google2SRT is a tool that can download "not embedded" subtitles (Closed Captions - CC) from YouTube and former Google Video and convert them to a standard format ([SubRip - SRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip)) supported by most video players.

There are some online tools, too, such as [keepsubs.com](http://keepsubs.com/) and [yousub.net](http://www.yousub.net) (although questionable how reliable).

Also, a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-caption-downloader/).

---

You could also use [OpenSubtitles.org](http://www.opensubtitles.org) to download subtitles soundtracks or concerts.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for are .lrc files aka scrollable lyrics