# Where can I find subtitled recordings of university courses?

Tags: data-request, language, education

I'm doing a research on the language used by university professors and I'm looking for closed captioned videos from real university classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any video on YouTube that has captions can be used, although you'll (probably) have to find a way to avoid auto-generated captions.

For example, from MIT (with friendly CC license). You can use open source tool [GoogleSRT](http://google2srt.sourceforge.net/en/download.html) or similar to download captions from YouTube.

See [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4005/1511) for more details.

[image]