# Are there any datasets publicly available for interviews transcripts?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, text

I am working on a project for behavioral analysis of interviewees using text data. Are there any available open datasets for interview transcripts, say telephonic interview transcripts or HR interview transcripts? The only available resource I found were video resumes on YouTube.

Comment: [Youtube subtitles seem to be downloadable](https://www.google.nl/search?q=download+youtube+subtitles)

Comment: @JanDoggen here's an older answer from this site https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4005/1511

Comment: do you mean only "job interviews"? probably journalistic interviews, or court cases, would be much easier to find transcripts for

Comment: @philshem yes, I am particularly looking for 'job interviews'. It would also be great if you can point me to any journalistic interview. I am not particularly keen on court cases.